# How to remove all instances of a character in textField using JButton?

Tags: java, string, jbutton, textfield

I am having trouble removing unwanted characters from my textField using my JButton. 
So far I have tried on button call using a for loop to go through the characters and replace all instances of alphabetical letters with 0. However the button is not actually doing anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated, here is my code:

```
    if(event.getSource() == call)
    {
        int length = search.getText().length();

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            char a;
            a = search.getText().charAt(i);
            if(!(a >= '0' && a <= '9') || !(a == '#') || !(a == '*')
            {
                  search.getText().replace(Character.toString(a), "");
            }
        }
     }
```

search is the name of my textField, on call I want to remove any character that is not between 0-9 or the # or * keys.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this line `search.getText().replace(Character.toString(a), "");`

should be like this

```
    search.setText(search.getText().replace(Character.toString(a), ""));
```

instead of changing and updating a character for each iteration you can do like this.

```
    String searchStr= search.getText();
    for(int i = 0; i < searchStr.length(); i++)
    {
        char a;
        a = searchStr.charAt(i);
        if(!(a >= '0' && a <= '9') || !(a == '#') || !(a == '*')
        {
             searchStr = searchStr.replace(Character.toString(a), "");
        }
    }
    search.setText(searchStr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working, however not quite in the way that I want it to, I will just have to adjust my logic on the if. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When using `replace` method it will return String.

```
/**
 * Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
 * sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
 * replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
 * example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
 * "ba" rather than "ab".
 *
 * @param  target The sequence of char values to be replaced
 * @param  replacement The replacement sequence of char values
 * @return  The resulting string
 * @throws NullPointerException if <code>target</code> or
 *         <code>replacement</code> is <code>null</code>.
 * @since 1.5
 */
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(
            this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

So when you use replace, you should use it like the following way:

```
` searchStr = searchStr.replace(Character.toString(a), ""); `
```

rather than `searchStr.replace(Character.toString(a), "");`

so that the value can be replaced.

If the code as you used previously `searchStr.replace(Character.toString(a), "");` String value searchStr, will not changed.

Additionaly, you can use regex to remove the unexpected chararters as well.
like,

```
if(event.getSource() == call)
{
       //remove any character that is not between 0-9 or the # or * keys.
            String text = search.getText();
            text = text.replaceAll("[^0-9#*]", "");
            //Set new text to search
            search.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well! This clears up the logic much better than going through each character individually. I have not learned much about regex, can you explain what "^[0-9*#]" is doing? My guess is that it is saying remove all except what is delimited by "[]"?

Comment: [^0-9*#] When a caret appears as the first character inside square brackets, it negates the pattern. This can match any character except any digital numbers from 0 to 9 or * or #. You can easily get the regrex basic knowledge from the following URL. http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: Ok thank you very much, this is very informative and is a very informative link.